# Update a text Field's value based on another date field passing a certain date

Tags: ms-access, vba, auto-update, ms-access-2016

For my Access database, I have a singular table with two fields - Award Status and Proposed Due Date. I want the Award Status to change to "Pending" once the Proposed Due Date has passed.

Currently, I am writing VBA to have the field update once the criteria is met.

```
Function AwardUpdate()

    Dim rstInput As DAO.Recordset
    Set rstInput = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestInput")

    With rstInput
        Do Until .EOF
            .Edit
            If .Fields(19) < Date And .Fields(29) = "Pre-Submission" Then
                .Fields(29) = "Pending"
                .MoveNext
            Else
                .MoveNext
            End If
        Loop
    End With

End Function
```

But I can't seem to get the criteria to check for if the Proposed Due Date is less than the current date.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well you have 2 criteria in your IF. Have you tested them individually to see which one is failing? Also, when are you running this code? It needs to get triggered somehow.

Comment: @HackSlash Yes, I have tested them individually. The date one is failing, which is what I'm mainly trying to figure out.
I am running this code within the Module editor at the moment. The goal was the have it run on database open/close so the end-user wouldn't have to press a button.

Comment: Add `Debug.print .Fields(19)` and `Debug.print Date` right before the `If` statement -- are those values as you expect?

Comment: There is a .Update  command missing. .Edit should come within if block. MoveNext should come out of if block. Also, why loop? Why not a standard SQL update command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - only editing where needed:

```
   Do Until .EOF
       If .Fields(19).Value < Date And .Fields(29).Value = "Pre-Submission" Then
           .Edit
               .Fields(29).Value = "Pending"
           .Update
       End If
       .MoveNext
   Loop
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much :)